# Получить значение из std::pair без пользовательского функтора в C++03

Tags: c++, c++03

Имеется код, который [работает в C++11](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yDBP0id3doyoWJIB):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::pair<void*, int> pair;

int main(){

    std::vector<pair> s;
    std::vector<int> r;

    pair p1(NULL, 42);
    pair p2(NULL, 100500);

    s.push_back(p1);
    s.push_back(p2);    

    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(r), static_cast<const int&(*)(const pair&)>(std::get<1>));
    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 42 100500
> ```

Хочется реализовать подобное в C++03 **без использования** пользовательского функтора/функции типа:

```
struct F {
    int operator()(const pair& p) { return p.second; }
};
```

или

```
int f(const pair& p) { return p.second; }
```

и вызова вида:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(r), F());
```

Можно ли это сделать с помощью цепочки готовых библиотечных адаптеров? `std::get` в C++03 ещё не было.

Использовать ручной цикл `for` вместо `transform` также не хочется, т.к. это влечёт за собой упоминание типов итераторов, да и не для того алгоритмы придуманы, чтобы вручную циклы писать.

Comment: Вряд ли, поскольку нет никакой функции, возвращающей одно значение из `pair`... С `pair` работает `map/multimap`, но как, загнав в него пары, потом выполнить обход для получения значений, и не упомянуть итератор уже для `map` (как я понимаю, это тоже не катит?) Насколько я помню, других стандартных применений `pair` нет. Даже если решение найдется - это будет нечто монстрообразное :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Международное [сообщество SO говорит](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023684/3240681), что нет стандартных функций для получения `first` и `second` членов `std::pair` в С++03. Как следствие, нет возможности и решить поставленную задачу. Всем спасибо за участие :)

Comment: не дотягивает пока наше сообщество))

Comment: @FORTRAN по кол-ву участников будем проигрывать, конечно. Но ответ, по большому счету, был предсказуем. Для надежного подтверждения отсутствия чего-либо требуется больше голосов, чем для подтверждения чего-то существующего.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::pair<void*, int> pair;

struct F {
    int operator()(const pair& p) { return p.second; }
};

int main(){

    std::vector<pair> s;
    std::vector<int> r;

    pair p1 = std::make_pair<void*, int>(NULL, 42);
    pair p2 = std::make_pair<void*, int>(0, 100500);

    s.push_back(p1);
    s.push_back(p2);

    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(r), F());
    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Компилятор MSVC 2010

Вывод:

```
42 100500
```

Comment: Что Вы хотели показать этим ответом?